# How to add an image to a term in a HOOK_install() of a module

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, installation

I was able to add a taxonomy term in the .install file in the hook_install() function, like this:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

class feature_basic_page_class{

  const feature_basic_page_terms = array('default', 'inverted');
  const feature_basic_page_vid = 'basic_page_layout';
}

function feature_basic_page_install(){
  $feature_basic_page_terms = feature_basic_page_class::feature_basic_page_terms;
  $feature_basic_page_vid = feature_basic_page_class::feature_basic_page_vid;
  foreach($feature_basic_page_terms as $feature_basic_page_term){
    $term = Term::create(array(
      'name' => $feature_basic_page_term,
      'description' => '',
      'parent' => array(0),
      'vid' => $feature_basic_page_vid
    ));
    $term->save();
  }
}

function feature_basic_page_uninstall(){
  $feature_basic_page_terms = feature_basic_page_class::feature_basic_page_terms;
  $feature_basic_page_vid = feature_basic_page_class::feature_basic_page_vid;
  $terms = array();
  foreach($feature_basic_page_terms as $feature_basic_page_term){
    if($terms_name = taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name($feature_basic_page_term, $feature_basic_page_vid)){
      $terms = array_merge($terms, $terms_name);
    }
  }
  foreach($terms as $term){
    $term->delete();
  }
}
```

I use a class because I tried a `global` variable and it was not working I don't know why...

Anyway, now I need to do the same thing for another module but this time the taxo term has an additional image field. I tried a few things but no success at this point:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

class feature_carrousel_class{

  const feature_carrousel_terms = [
    array('name' => 'left', 'overlay' => 'images/BRAVA_Image_Forme.png'),
    array('name' => 'right', 'overlay' => 'images/BRAVA_Image_Forme.png')
  ];
  const feature_carrousel_vid = 'layout';
}

function feature_carrousel_install(){
  $feature_carrousel_terms = feature_carrousel_class::feature_carrousel_terms;
  $feature_carrousel_vid = feature_carrousel_class::feature_carrousel_vid;
  foreach($feature_carrousel_terms as $feature_carrousel_term){
    $term = Term::create(array(
      'name' => $feature_carrousel_term['name'],
      'field_overlay_image' => $feature_carrousel_term['overlay'],
      'description' => '',
      'parent' => array(0),
      'vid' => $feature_carrousel_vid
    ));
    $term->save();
  }
}

function feature_carrousel_uninstall(){
  $feature_carrousel_terms = feature_carrousel_class::feature_carrousel_terms;
  $feature_carrousel_vid = feature_carrousel_class::feature_carrousel_vid;
  $terms = array();
  foreach($feature_carrousel_terms as $feature_carrousel_term){
    if($terms_name = taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name($feature_carrousel_term['name'], $feature_carrousel_vid)){
      $terms = array_merge($terms, $terms_name);
    }
  }
  foreach($terms as $term){
    $term->delete();
  }
}
```

I get this error:

`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Call to a member function getFileUri() on null in Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem->preSave() (line 317 of core/modules/image/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/ImageItem.php).
Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem->preSave() (Line: 244)
Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList->delegateMethod('preSave') (Line: 202)
Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList->preSave() (Line: 449)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeFieldMethod('preSave', Object) (Line: 406)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeHook('presave', Object) (Line: 435)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPreSave(Object) (Line: 291)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPreSave(Object) (Line: 389)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object) (Line: 747)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save(Object) (Line: 358)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save() (Line: 24)
feature_carrousel_install()
call_user_func_array('feature_carrousel_install', Array) (Line: 391)`

This sound like a bad path for my image, but I don't know how to call my image correctly. My images are located at the root of my module in an images/ folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image field is basically an entity reference field.

So what you do is you create a file entity first, save that, and then assign the file id or file entity object to your image field, plus alt/title if you want that.

http://realityloop.com/blog/2015/10/08/programmatically-attach-files-node-drupal-8 seems like a pretty good blog post about that. nodes or terms doesn't a difference here.

The critical part ( to make drupal answers moderators happy ;)):

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;


// Create file object from remote URL.
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon.small_.png');
$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://druplicon.png', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// Create node object with attached file.
$node = Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
  ],
]);
$node->save();
```

That assumes fetching the file data from somewhere, there are also examples that create it with an already existing file.

Comment: You are my Drupal Super Star! It was indeed the other way. I put in my module images sub dir the images I need, then with the magic `$uri  = file_unmanaged_copy('public://source.jpg', 'public://destination.jpg', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);` I was able to achieve my goal. Thanks